# .NET Pinning handle in memory dump with no interop or fixed

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am investigating memory dump from production and I see lot of references with "Pinning handle" as you can see on screenshot below (from Jetbrains dotMemory). We are not using fixed and we are not doing anything with unmanaged resources around this code so I would like to ask how is that possible? SiteManager class is singleton so there is

```
private static SiteManager _instance;
```

field in code which keeps reference to that object forever. But I don't see any reason why this would cause pinning.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the array of objects is one of the internal CLR objects used to store static references. So it is not your object pinned, it's array keeping static references pinned.

**[EDIT]**
I said "most likely" because I don't know your program. If you, as an author of this program, sure that it is not "your" `object[]`, that's for sure it is an array keeping "static reference GC root".

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilercallback2-rootreferences2-method) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) you can read a little about GC roots

But there is nothing about array of objects due to it seems the internal .NET implementation details. I know about it from my experience as a dotMemory developer.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Ed.ward. Do you have any more info on this topic? Any links where it would be deeply explained?

Comment: Updated the post